# Run multiple charging circuits on the same battery

Tags: resistors, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I've recently purchased a set of 3.7V 1A Li-Ion charging circuits available [HERE](http://www.ebay.com/itm/331244102819?_trksid=p2060778.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT) and was wondering if i could charge the same battery using multiples of these to get a quicker charge. Is there any safe way to do it?

***UPDATE***

Heres another idea, Is there a way to use multiple batteries and multiple charging circuits to the charge would take less time yet still have the same capacity?

Comment: No, you don't want to do that. The circuits are set up to control the charging current based on the batteries state. Hooking multiples up to the same battery will mess up the charging cycle. If you want a faster charging cycle, get a different, faster/higher current charger.

Comment: Not a good idea BUT would probably work in CC part of cycle. When the battery reached the 4.2V CV part of the cycle massive interactions may occur. Failing to terminate in CC mode shortens battery life. | Failing to keep CV voltage under Vmax may grossly shorten battery life, plus that of surrounding items. | Battery MUST NOT be charged at above manufactures specified Imax which is usually C/1.

Answer (score 2):

First, remember you should not be charging it at more than 1C, so if you have a 2 Amp-hour battery, do not charge it at more than 2A. I suspect your charging circuits will not work operating on the same battery, as they will interfere with each other's charge cycle/detection processes.

If you want to charge at a higher charge current (and therefore, quicker charge) and you have a nice big battery (like a 5 amp-hour one for example, single cell) then you may be able to find something like a 3 or 5 Amp charger, often they are dedicated battery charging stations with multiple banks and can do even tens of amps.

For a small integrated circuit solution, you may find it hard to get much more than 1.5-2A current output. I suggest you do NOT put multiple charge controllers onto the same battery.